# Add data to file name (ASP.NET WEB API)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have WebAPI method that writes image to folder. It works well.

Here is code of method

```
[Route("api/PostUserImage")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUserImage()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        try
        {

            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    int MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 1; //Size = 1 MB  

                    IList<string> AllowedFileExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };
                    var ext = postedFile.FileName.Substring(postedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                    var extension = ext.ToLower();
                    if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(extension))
                    {

                        var message = string.Format("Please Upload image of type .jpg,.gif,.png.");

                        dict.Add("error", message);
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                    }
                    else if (postedFile.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
                    {

                        var message = string.Format("Please Upload a file upto 1 mb.");

                        dict.Add("error", message);
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        var date = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Image/" + postedFile.FileName+date+ extension);

                        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                    }
                }

                var message1 = string.Format("Image Updated Successfully.");
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, message1); ;
            }
            var res = string.Format("Please Upload a image.");
            dict.Add("error", res);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var res = string.Format("some Message");
            dict.Add("error", res);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
        }
    }
```

Now FileName is getting from file name. But I need to add date to file name.

I try to do it like this:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Image/" + postedFile.FileName+date+ extension);
```

But it doesn't works. I am getting error when send image

How I can do this?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Please show the error you are getting.

Comment: Problem is alreaвy solved

Comment: Sorry, it showed up in the review queue without showing whether it had been answered. Generally whenever you receive an error you want to include it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make date format without slashes 
for example use this code

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyHHmmss")
```

Note : you can change the format of the date so it can be `ddMMyyHHmmss` and so on